# How to stop killing my pip mode in onPause when my app is on Sleep mode?

Tags: java, android

When My app is on PIP(Picture in Picture Mode) mode and i locked my phone , or checked after 5 or  6 minutes in my app, PIP mode killed,  i don't know why my PIP(Picture in Picture Mode) is killed, when my app on sleep mode, and its happen only some phones not every phones.please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to run a `service` and start the `PIP` from the service to make Android not kill `PIP mode`. The service should be a `foreground service`, or it will be killed in some situations.

Refer to the following documentation to get a better understanding:

[PIP Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture)

[Foreground Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services)

Comment: i Also tried to run foreground service in background but its also killed

Comment: Can you share the code or the error message(if any)?

Comment: no error sir i found only pip mode killed i am stuck on it